# Angular2 html markup bind to boolean flag and call method when false

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I'm attempting to write a workaround for angular2 bootstrap datepicker that closes the datepicker when a user clicks outside.

*I have it working where a click outside is registered and flips a boolean flag here:*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ngbd-datepicker-popup',
    templateUrl: 'app/component/datepicker/datepicker.html',
    host: {
        '(document:click)': 'handleClick($event)'
    }
})

export class NgbdDatepickerPopup {

    private showDatePicker: boolean = true;


    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}



    handleClick(event: any) {
        if (!this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
            this.showDatePicker = false;
        } 
    }

}
```

The only problem is, I don't know what to do from there to close the datepicker. I need to call the `close()` method from the markup because that's where my datepicker is declared.

*Here's the markup with comments:*

```
<form class="form-inline" bindToBooleanFlagHere="d.close()"> <!--if true, close the popup --!>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" style="z-index: 0;" readOnly class="form-control" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" firstDayOfWeek="1"
               name="dp" [(ngModel)]="date" (ngModelChange)="dateChange(date)" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker"> <!-- datepicker declared here --!>
            <div *ngIf="!disableThis" class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: white; cursor: pointer" (click)="d.toggle()">
                <i class="glyphicon calendar"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My datepicker object is declared as `d` here in the HTML markup and external clicks are registered in the typescript. These external clicks flip my boolean flag to false.

So I need my html to watch this boolean flag and call the `d.close()` method when `showDatePicker` is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hacks on hacks on hacks**

I'm not sure if I'm proud of this solution, but this whole issue arose because Angular2 Bootstrap Datepickers don't support this behavior.

*So here's what I did:*

First of all, duplicate html markup based off of the boolean flag.

```
<form class="form-inline" *ngIf="showDatePicker">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" style="z-index: 0;" readOnly class="form-control" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" firstDayOfWeek="1"
                   name="dp" [(ngModel)]="date" (ngModelChange)="dateChange(date)" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
            <div *ngIf="date != null" class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: white; cursor: pointer" (click)="clearDate()"><i class="glyphicon remove"></i>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="!disableThis" class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: white; cursor: pointer" (click)="d.toggle()">
                <i class="glyphicon calendar"></i>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="disableThis" class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: white; cursor: pointer">
                <i class="glyphicon calendar"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<form *ngIf="!showDatePicker" class="form-inline" (mousemove)="d.close(); resetShowDatePicker();">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" style="z-index: 0;" readOnly class="form-control" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" firstDayOfWeek="1"
                   name="dp" [(ngModel)]="date" (ngModelChange)="dateChange(date)" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
            <div *ngIf="date != null" class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: white; cursor: pointer" (click)="clearDate()">
                <i class="glyphicon remove"></i>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="!disableThis" class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: white; cursor: pointer" (click)="d.toggle()">
                <i class="glyphicon calendar"></i>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="disableThis" class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: white; cursor: pointer">
                <i class="glyphicon calendar"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When `showDatePicker` is false, the close function occurs on `mousemove` which gives the *appearance* of the datepicker closing once the click occurs. Then the boolean flag is reset to true so the user can open it again seemlessly.

*And here's the component code:*

```
handleClick(event: any) {
    if (this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement.contains(event.target) ||
        event.target.className === 'glyphicon calendar') {
        // glyphicon calendar is the class name of the button icon that opens the datepicker
        this.showDatePicker = true;
    } else {
        this.showDatePicker = false;
    }
}

resetShowDatePicker(): void {
    this.showDatePicker = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a reference of the component and then call close on it

```
@ViewChild(NgbDatePicker) popup:NgbdDatepickerPopup;

handleClick() {
  if (!this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
     this.popup.close();
  } 
}
```

I'm not sure if the `@ViewChild()` line is correct, because I don't fully understand your code.

Comment: Do you have any specific questions about my code? What don't you understand?

Comment: What component you want to call `close()` on.

Comment: `d` is declared here `ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker"` as the ngbDatepicker object.  So, when an event is triggered, it closes the datepicker

Comment: What event has to be triggered where?

Comment: edited the post for clarity, does this make sense now?

Comment: I updated my answer. There is not really a way for calling a method from the view when a field changes.